# Why do I get a null exception on post in my DropDownListFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I know this sounds like every other question on the net about this but it's actually not. I have tried finding the right answer high and low so as to not waste anyone's time but to no avail. I should also add that I am pretty new to MVC.NET.

I have an MVC 4 view with a DropDownListFor call that throws a null ref exception on post. I am trying to test a submit with nothing selected scenario i.e. the default selection is selected. Ideally, it will get picked up and yell at me with a required field message. I see that the Province model property is in fact set to -1 on the post, so that works.

Now this is where my question deviates from most others. I am pretty sure that the model is being passed correctly and that the SelectList is populated. I have set a breakpoint on the line in the view and am seeing it populated on the post just before it blows up. My code seems to look like every other example I have seen.

I very much appreciate any help you can provide.

At the end, I will paste the yellow screen info.

So here are the snippets, I cut out the bulk of it so you're not overwhelmed with non-relevant code:

View:

```
@using GymManagement.UI.Models
@model UserModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Province, Model.ProvinceList, new {@id="ProvincePersonal", @class="inputField", @value="@Model.Province"})
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateMember()
{
    return CreateUser();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateMember(UserModel model)
{
    return CreateUser(model);
}

private ActionResult CreateUser()
{
    var model = new UserModel();

    PrepareModel(model, false);

    return View(model);
}

private ActionResult CreateUser(UserModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return DisplayUser(model);
    }

    PrepareModel(model, true);

    return View(model);
}

private void PrepareModel(UserModel model, bool isPostback)
{
    // other items removed for brevity

    if (Session["Provinces"] == null || ((List<Province>)Session["Provinces"]).Count == 0)
    {
        var serviceClient = ServiceProxy.GetLookupService();
        var provinces = serviceClient.GetProvinces(); // Returns List<Province>

        provinces = provinces.OrderBy(p => p.ProvinceName).ToList();
        Session["Provinces"] = provinces;
        model.Provinces = provinces;
    }
    else
    {
        model.Provinces = ((List<Province>)Session["Provinces"]);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
// base model
public class BaseModel
{
    public BaseModel()
    {
        Provinces = new List<Province>();
    }
    public List<Province> Provinces { get; set; } 
}

// user model
public int Province { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProvinceList
{
    get
    {
        var list = new SelectList(Provinces, "ProvinceId", "ProvinceName");
        var defaultItem = Enumerable.Repeat(new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = "-1",
            Text = "Select province"
        }, count: 1);

        defaultItem = defaultItem.Concat(list);

        if (Province != 0)
        {
            var selectedItem = Province.ToString();
            var province = defaultItem.First(p => p.Value.Equals(selectedItem));
            province.Selected = true;
        }

        return defaultItem;
    }
}
```

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Stack Trace:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>      ASP._Page_Views_user_CreateMember_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\Mike\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\GymManagement\GymManagement.UI\Views\User\CreateMember.cshtml:46
>      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +279
>      System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +124
>      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +180
>      System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +379
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.b__17() +32
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +613
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +263
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +240
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Comment: What's the actual exception that's thrown?

Comment: Why do you think you would get a 'Required message' - a value of `-1` is valid for typeof `int`. Not really sure what your trying to achieve with all this code. It can be reduced down to just a few lines.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Hi Stephen, the required was back when I had a nullable<int> I forgot to get rid of it. Sorry.

Comment: DropDownListFor has an overload for a default value. Use that instead of  your current code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only you can step through an debug your code to determine which object is null and hence throwing the exception. But the real issue is that you have over complicated a simple concept with a lot of pointless code. It can simply be

View model

```
public Class UserViewModel
{
  ... // other properties of User
  [Display(Name = "Province")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please select a province")]
  public int ProvinceID { get; set; }
  public SelectList ProvinceList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  UserViewModel model = new UserViewModel();
  ConfigureViewModel(model);
  return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Create(UserViewModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
  }
  // Save and redirect
}

private void ConfigureViewModel(UserViewModel model)
{
  var provinces = serviceClient.GetProvinces();
  model.ProvinceList = new SelectList(provinces, "ProvinceId", "ProvinceName");
}
```

View

```
@model UserViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  ....
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProvinceID)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProvinceID, Model.ProvinceList, "Please select", new { @class="inputField" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProvinceID)
  ....
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a go. Thanks. Will this maintain the value through post back i the event of an error?

Comment: Yes, of course. But if you include the relevant scripts for client side validation (jquery.validation.unobtrusive.js) , you will get the error message and the submit will be prevented anyway until the user selects a valid option.

Comment: Hey Stephen, Thanks for the help. I am still getting an error on that line. Some of the extra code was me trying different things to work around an issue I saw as a possible problem. I started out with the textbook example which does not seem complicated. In debug when hovering over the Model keyword in the DropDownListFor method and then reviewing the list contents of the SelectList, they are all there as expected. The ProvinceId is still 0 because the selected option is the default which has a value of String.Empty.

Comment: Actually when I cut everything out of the view and used entirely the razor code rather than my own html, it worked! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Check that every "ProvinceId" values are not nulls, because you have

```
var list = new SelectList(Provinces, "ProvinceId", "ProvinceName");
```

and then

```
var province = defaultItem.First(p => p.Value.Equals(selectedItem));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. All items have id's and the error was occurring before I added that code.

Comment: Then ensure on code that you can yield the entire `Model.ProvinceList` and the value `Model.Province`.

Comment: I find strange the `@value="@Model.Province` can you remove that and check if you really need that? DropdownListFor shoud select the value of the m.Province

Comment: Hi Joao, I added it so the value would be maintained during post back. As far as yield, can you please elaborate? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

So based on Stephen's example, I stripped my view back and gradually added elements back in. As it turns out, my business address province was conflicting with my personal address province. The issue was tunnel vision combined with a bizarre location for the null reference exception. Thanks everyone for your ideas and help!